No profiles for 'xyz' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching xyz (works locally)
Azure DevOps Server type
dev.azure.com (formerly visualstudio.com)
Azure DevOps Server Version (if applicable)
No response
Operation system
MacOS
Question
I am trying to run a Azure Pipeline for Task Name: Xcode@5.
Xcode@5 fails to build an Xcode project couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching profile_name, resulting in a Code Signing Error with this format:
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS-14'

resources:
 repositories:
 - repository: AheLineIOS
   type: git
   name: AheLineIOS/AheLineIOS
   trigger:
     branches:
       include:
       - deneme
     paths:
       include:
       - AHELine.UI/*
       - AheLine.Robo/*
       - AHELine.Data/*
       - AHELine.Common/*
       - Pods/*
       exclude:
       - ExportOptions_prod.plist

steps:
- checkout: AheLineIOS
  clean: true

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Select Xcode Version
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo Mac OS version:
      sw_vers -productVersion
      echo Installed Xcode versions:
      ls /Applications | grep 'Xcode'
      echo currently selected xcode:
      xcrun xcode-select --print-path
      echo selecting latest xcode...
      sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_15.0.1.app
      xcrun xcode-select --print-path
      echo Selected Xcode version:
      xcodebuild -version
      xcodebuild -downloadAllPlatforms
  
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'DistributionCertificates2024.p12'
    certPwd: '$(provisioningProfilePassword2)'
    keychain: 'temp'
  
- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@0
  inputs:
    provProfileSecureFile: 'AheMobilProd.mobileprovision'
    removeProfile: true
  
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'clean'
    configuration: 'Release'
    sdk: 'iphoneos'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'AheLine.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'AHELine.UI'
    packageApp: true
    signingOption: 'auto'
    useXcpretty: false

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: Copy ipa file
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'output/$(SDK)/$(Configuration)'
    Contents: '*.ipa'
    TargetFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/ipa'
    CleanTargetFolder: true
    OverWrite: true

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: 'output/$(SDK)/$(Configuration)'
    artifact: 'ipaRelease'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'

Important section where error is generated from in Xcode@5 task:
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'clean'
    configuration: 'Release'
    sdk: 'iphoneos'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'AheLine.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'AHELine.UI'
    packageApp: true
    signingOption: 'auto'
    useXcpretty: false


Here's the output where I recieve the error:
/Users/runner/work/1/s/AHELine.UI/AHELine.UI.xcodeproj: 
error: No profiles for 'com.ahe.aheline' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.ahe.aheline'. 
Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. 
To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'AHELine.UI' from project 'AHELine.UI')
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


##[error]Error: The process '/usr/bin/xcodebuild' failed with exit code 65

=> InstallAppleCertificate: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/64943138a05f5ca67afcd2d0361429df
=> InstallAppleProvisioningProfile: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/73f926e1e5c89d90504a57095193fe16

I do not think that your issue is strictly related with the issue https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/12263


Please share your latest YAML file which use signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)' and provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)' in Xcode task. By the way, it's suggested that you could use the latest InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1 task, since version 0.* has been deprecated.



For new error "createItemModels creation requirements should not create capability item model for a capability item model that already exists.", try to revoke certificate and try again. Or use Xcode with another version. It seems to be a known bug in version 15.



What's the version of the Xcode on your local machine? 4. What's the result if you set up a self-hosted agent on your working local machine and run the pipeline using this self-hosted agent?


@ZiyangLiu-MSFT The warnings about the capability item model that already exists do not look related to build Error code 65

@cristallo, agree with you. It would be better to enable verbose log and check if there is any detailed error message. Since it works locally, I am guessing it's related to the environment or the profile itself. So that I suggest him to try the self-hosted agent.

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT Sorry what do you mean by self-hosted agent? Do you have any recommendation for this?

@alper, Set up a self-hosted agent on your working local machine. Then run the pipeline using this agent.

Unfortunately, setting up a self-hosted agent might not be a trivial task, especially in a complex IT-managed work environment, and not all solutions usable for SEFL-hosted can be used on an Azure-hosted machine. I suggest you continue to investigate error 65 and try to increase the verbosity of the log.

On azure hosted macOS machine you cannot use the signingOption="auto" but you have to use signingOption="manual" with specific $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY) $(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID) variables.
InstallAppleCertificate and InstallAppleProvisioningProfile tasks set both variables for you.
task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'archive'
    configuration: 'Release'
    sdk: 'iphoneos'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'AheLine.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'AHELine.UI'
    packageApp: true
    signingOption: 'manual'
    signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
    provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'

You may also need to remove the following lines:
useXcpretty: false
args: '-verbose CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=No'
exportOptions: 'specify'
teamId: "Team Id" 
exportTeamId: "Team Id"

signingOption="auto" option is designed to be used on Self-hosted macOS machine with a properly pre-configured Apple account.
Note that the certificate and provisioning profile must match, in my case I preferred to manually generate the distribution ones instead of using the XCode auto-generated ones.

Now, with your solution I am having error message regarding to archieve. ** ARCHIVE FAILED ** ##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65. Full log: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/e51c2202ebb06f5c22192639425409ca

Usually, Error code 65 indicates problems with the signing of the application. Are you sure that the provisioning profile file was generated using the right certificate?

I am also not sure if the args: 'CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=No' is needed or not

Why are you using actions: 'clean' in your xcode task?
Probably it should be actions: 'archive'

The documentation about xcode build on azure pipeline is definitely not clear. Do not give up! :-)

I will try in archive as well.  Are you sure that the provisioning profile file was generated using the right certificate?. I will double check this

@alper My two cents: looking at your log, I see that the certificate is something like Apple Development... but my expectation was something like Apple Distribution...

@alper Is it still related to error code 65? Can you share the Xcode@5 task that is generating this error?

Please see my update question with latest configuration

This is a really bad way to use stckoverflow, if you change the question than the previous answer has no sense at all. If the question is different then you should open a new question.

That said: if you're still using the auto signing option, it won't work on an Azure-hosted MacOS machine.
